# How to properly setup firebase phone auth in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase phone auth in my flutter app, I have cross-checked:

- Google Play Integrity API is enabled (Android Device Verification deprecated)
- Enabled APP CHECK in firebase
- Added SHAs from android by running the command ./grdlew SignInRepot
- Re-download the googleservices.json for android
  But every time I test it on a real android device, I got the captcha check. Is there something I am missing? How can I get rid of the captcha?

I HAVE TRIED EVERY POSSIBLE SOLUTION, LIKE SHAs, ENABLING THE APIS, ETC

Answer (score 0):

I removed captcha by adding this code in Java.

```
FirebaseAuth.getFirebaseAuthSettings().setAppVerificationDisabledForTesting(true);
```

Hope this will be helpful for you.